# Float error when writing Celsius-Fahrenheit converter (Zelle)

Tags: python

I'm currently learning Python from Zelle's book, and wrote the following Celsius to Fahrenheit converter. It works without issue:

```
print("This program will convert Celsius to Fahrenheit")
c = eval(input("Input the temperature in Celsius: "))
for i in range(10):
    f = c * (9/5) + 32
    print(f)
```

Zelle asks to later adapt this so that every ten degrees from 0 to 100 Celsius are converted to Fahrenheit, and set on top of one another like columns. I wrote it like this:

```
print("This program will do 10 temperature conversions.")
c = [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
f = c * (9/5) + 32
for i in range(1):
    print(c)
for i in range(1):
    print(f)
```

I get the following errors:

1) If I leave it as is, the error states: "line 63, in fourthprogram
    f = c * (9/5) + 32  TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'"

2) If I change (9/5) to another number, like 2, the error states: "line 63, in fourthprogram
    f = c * 2 + 32
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

So, there's a couple of things going on here that I can't quite figure out. The "float" error, according to other answers on Stack Overflow, often relate to variables treated as strings, but it looks like the variables are given a numerical value here. The other error, I tried rewriting the list in the options given by Zelle in Ch 2 and prior, but it's not helping.

How do I deal with this float error, specifically, and other more complex float errors in the future?

Zelle has answers up on his website, but I'd like to know why my code doesn't work as written.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `eval`. If you are expecting a floating-point value, use `c = float(input(...))`. If the input is not a valid floating-point literal, you *want* an exception to be raised so that you can handle it, rather than having a possibly random Python expression be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because you are trying to do mathematical operations on the entire list 'c'. Python requires you to access the elements before operating on them. You have two options:

1) Use a for loop or list comprehension to do elementwise operations on your list. For example:

```
f = [x * (9/5) + 32 for x in c]
```

Will give you a list of all ten temperatures converted to fahrenheit.

2) If you'd like to get more advanced, you can use numpy. Numpy is a highly optimized library for doing math, and supports the vectorized operation syntax that seems natural to you. In other words, it automatically applies math operations to every element of the array, so just changing the first two lines of your code to read:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.array([0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])
```

will work.

As an aside, once you've made either of those changes, there's no need for the

```
for i in range(1):
    print(c)
```

loops. Just print(c), it will make your code easier to read.